# Css not linked to html

Tags: html, css

I have a html file and my css file. After searching for a lot of Suggestions I put them in seperate folders but I can't link the `index.css` with the `index.html`. My code is provided Below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body    style = ' text-align : center;'>
    <p id = 'Come'>Welcome</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

and my css file:

```
#Come{
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

My file structure:

```
App
  |
   index.html
   styles
        |
         index.css
```

Pls Help

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You need to do some debugging (e.g. use the Network tab in your browser's developer tools to see what URL is being requested to load the CSS and what response you are getting).

Comment: can you share the url, please?

Comment: code looks fine. Did you copy/paste it here (html and also css), or did you write it or a part of it? If so, you could have some typo there (css file name, link's href, style declaration in css...)

Comment: There is no typo, I have pasted the file name from visual studio

Comment: also I use pure Intellisense of Visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try replacing the `href` value to `"./styles/index.css"`

and also try to remove spaces from `id = 'Come'`

it should look something like this: `id="Come"`

Comment: `./styles/` and `styles/` mean exactly the same thing. That is a pointless change.

Comment: Removing that white space is also a pointless change that won't help.

Comment: I know, but I couldn't identify where is this problem actually rooting from so I said: "try". Cheers :)

Comment: My bad, I thought we were all just trying to help here. No bad intentions, cheers!

Comment: They are both the same

Comment: No Problem cedx

Answer (score 0):

There was a Glitch guys. I restarted my computer and CSS loaded